# Problem with TableOfContent ReportLab doc.notify does not generate in TOC

Tags: python, django, reportlab

I have a problem with TableOfContent ReportLab doc.notify does not generate in TOC. Direct call to doc.notify does not generate in TableOfContent. Calling afterFlowable(doc, f) to definition does not generate a TableOfContent. Only direct doc.notify call in myLaterPages definition works, but of course it generates list of all pages with static string "Chapter". Where do I go wrong?

````
from django.http import FileResponse
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
import reportlab.pdfgen
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Paragraph, Spacer, PageBreak
#from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet, ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont  
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents, SimpleIndex
#from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A5
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT
PAGESIZE = (140 * mm, 216 * mm)
BASE_MARGIN = 5 * mm

def generatePDF(request,id):
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Berylium', 'resources/fonts/Berylium/Berylium.ttf'))
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumBd', './resources/fonts/Berylium/Beryliumbold.ttf'))
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumIt', './resources/fonts/Berylium/BeryliumItalic.ttf'))
    pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumBI', './resources/fonts/Berylium/BeryliumboldItalic.ttf'))
    registerFontFamily('Berylium', normal='Berylium', bold='BeryliumBd', italic='BeryliumIt', boldItalic='BeryliumBI')
    
    PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]
    PAGE_WIDTH=defaultPageSize[0]
    
    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    Title = book.title
    pageinfo = book.title
    Author = book.author
    Filename = book.title

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            style = flowable.style.name
            if style == 'style1':
                self.notify('TOCEntry', (0, text, self.page +2))
                print(text,  self.page + 2)

    def myFirstPage(canvas, doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('BeryliumBd',18)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-190, Title)
        canvas.setFont('BeryliumIt',14)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-210, Author)
        canvas.setFont('Berylium',9)
        canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, " ")
        canvas.restoreState()
        canvas.showPage()
        
    def myLaterPages(canvas, doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('Berylium', 9)
        canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch,"Page %d %s" % (doc.page, pageinfo))
        canvas.restoreState()
        doc.notify('TOCEntry', (0, "Chapter", doc.page)) 
        # Here section direct call to doc.notify but of course it generates list of all pages with static inscription "Chapter"
        
    def go():
        
        doc = SimpleDocTemplate(filename=Filename, title=book.title, author=book.author)  
        style1 = ParagraphStyle('style1',
                                alignment=TA_CENTER,
                                fontName='BeryliumBd',
                                fontSize=14)
        style2 = ParagraphStyle('style2',
                                alignment=TA_JUSTIFY,
                                fontName='Berylium',
                                fontSize=11)

        chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(book_id = id)
        chapterNum = 0
        toc = TableOfContents() 
        toc.levelStyles = [style1, style2]
        Story = []      
        Story.append(Paragraph("""Table of Contents:""", style1))
        Story.append(toc)
        Story.append(PageBreak())
        
        for i in chapters:            
            doc.multiBuild(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages )
            
            chapterNum += 1
            Story.append(Spacer(2,1*inch))
            Story.append(Paragraph("Chapter " + str(chapterNum), style1))
            d = (" %s" %  i.title_chapter )
            doc.notify('TOCEntry', (0, i.title_chapter, doc.page +2))# Direct call to doc.notify does not generate in TableOfContent
            #toc.addEntry(0, i.title_chapter , chapterNum, None)            
            #print(d,  doc.page +2)
            
            f = Paragraph(d, style1)
            afterFlowable(doc,f) #Calling afterFlowable(doc, f) does not generate a TableOfContent
            Story.append(Spacer(1,0.2*inch))
            Story.append(f)

            Story.append(Spacer(2,1*inch))
            e = (" %s" % i.content )
            g = Paragraph(e, style2)
            Story.append(g)
            Story.append(PageBreak())
            doc.multiBuild(Story, onFirstPage=myFirstPage, onLaterPages=myLaterPages )

    go()
    
    return HttpResponse(open(Filename, 'br'), content_type='application/pdf')  ```
````

Answer (score 1):

It took me a bit but I found a solution and some new interesting additions. Maybe someone will need it ...

````
from reportlab.rl_config import defaultPageSize
from django.http import HttpResponse
from reportlab.lib.styles import ParagraphStyle
from reportlab.lib.units import mm, inch, cm
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.pdfmetrics import registerFontFamily
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont  
from reportlab.platypus.tableofcontents import TableOfContents
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import A4
from reportlab.lib.enums import TA_JUSTIFY, TA_LEFT, TA_CENTER, TA_RIGHT

class MyDocTemplate(BaseDocTemplate):
    
    def __init__(self, filename, **kw):
        self.allowSplitting = 0
        BaseDocTemplate.__init__(self, filename, **kw)

    def afterFlowable(self, flowable):
        "Registers TOC entries."
        if flowable.__class__.__name__ == 'Paragraph':
            text = flowable.getPlainText()
            E = [0, text, self.page]
            bn = getattr(flowable,'_bookmarkName',None)
            if bn is not None: 
                E.append(bn), 
                self.notify('TOCEntry', tuple(E))
            else:
                return

def generatePDF(request, id):
    Frame1=Frame(2.5*cm, 2.3*cm, 16*cm, 25*cm,id='F1')
    PAGE_HEIGHT=defaultPageSize[1]
    PAGE_WIDTH=defaultPageSize[0]
    
    top_margin = A4[1] - inch
    bottom_margin = inch
    left_margin = inch
    right_margin = A4[0] - inch

    book = Book.objects.get(id=id)
    Title = book.title
    Author = book.author
    pageinfo = "%s / %s " % (Author, Title)
    file_name = book.title
    doc = MyDocTemplate(file_name)

    def drawPageFrame(canv):
        canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
        canv.setFont('Berylium',9)
        canv.drawString(left_margin, top_margin + 2, pageinfo)
        canv.line(left_margin, top_margin, right_margin, top_margin)
        canv.line(left_margin, bottom_margin, right_margin, bottom_margin)
        canv.drawCentredString(0.5*A4[0], 0.5 * inch,"Page %d" % canv.getPageNumber())

    def myFirstPage(canvas, doc):
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('BeryliumBd',18)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-190, Title)
        canvas.setFont('BeryliumIt',14)
        canvas.drawCentredString(PAGE_WIDTH/2.0, PAGE_HEIGHT-210, Author)
        canvas.setFont('Berylium',9)
        canvas.drawString(inch, 0.75 * inch, " ")
        canvas.restoreState()
            
    def myLaterPages(canvas, doc):
        
        #page_num = canvas.getPageNumber()
        #key = 'ch%s' % doc.seq.nextf('style0')
        #canvas.bookmarkPage(key)
        #doc.notify('TOCEntry', (0, 'Chapter 1', page_num, key))
        #canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setAuthor(book.author)
        canvas.setTitle(book.title)
        canvas.setSubject("BooksBe")           
        drawPageFrame(canvas)
    
    def go():
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Berylium', 'resources/fonts/Berylium/Berylium.ttf'))
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumBd', './resources/fonts/Berylium/Beryliumbold.ttf'))
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumIt', './resources/fonts/Berylium/BeryliumItalic.ttf'))
        pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('BeryliumBI', './resources/fonts/Berylium/BeryliumboldItalic.ttf'))
        registerFontFamily('Berylium', normal='Berylium', bold='BeryliumBd', italic='BeryliumIt', boldItalic='BeryliumBI')

        chapters = Chapter.objects.filter(book_id = id)
        chapterNum = 0

        Story = []  

        style0 = ParagraphStyle('style0',
                                alignment=TA_LEFT,
                                fontName='BeryliumBd',
                                fontSize=12) 
        style1 = ParagraphStyle('style1',
                                alignment=TA_CENTER,
                                fontName='BeryliumBd',
                                leading = 14,
                                fontSize=14)
        style2 = ParagraphStyle('style2',
                                alignment=TA_JUSTIFY,
                                fontName='Berylium',
                                leading = 14,
                                fontSize=11)
        doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='TitlePage', frames=Frame1, onPage=myFirstPage),PageTemplate(id='ContentPage', frames=Frame1, onPage=myLaterPages)])

        Story.append(NextPageTemplate('TitlePage'))
        Story.append(NextPageTemplate('ContentPage'))
        Story.append(PageBreak())
        Story.append(Spacer(2,1*inch))
        Story.append(Paragraph("""Table of Contents:""", style1))
        Story.append(Spacer(1,0.3*inch))
        toc = TableOfContents() 
        toc.levelStyles = [style0, style1, style2]        
        Story.append(toc)
        Story.append(PageBreak())

        def doHeading(text,sty):
            from hashlib import sha1
            bn=sha1((text+sty.name).encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
            h=Paragraph(text+'<a name="%s"/>' % bn, sty)
            h._bookmarkName=bn
            Story.append(h) 

        for i in chapters:        
            Story.append(NextPageTemplate('ContentPage'))    
            doc.multiBuild(Story)
            chapterNum += 1
            Story.append(Spacer(2,1*inch))
            Story.append(Paragraph("Chapter " + str(chapterNum), style1))
            Story.append(Spacer(2,0.2*inch))
            d = (" %s" % i.title_chapter  )
            doHeading(d, style1)
            Story.append(Spacer(2,1*inch))
            e = (" %s" % i.content )
            str(e).replace('\n','<br />\n')
            g = Paragraph(e, style2)
            Story.append(g)
            Story.append(PageBreak())
            doc.multiBuild(Story)
    go()
    
    return HttpResponse(open(book.title, 'br'), content_type='application/pdf') ```
````